# Spontanous emission same selection rules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I have just read (see [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qKaRmHd_iIwC&pg=PA177&dq=selection%20rules%20for%20spontaneous%20emission%20are%20all%20the%20same&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxx_SUh9_OAhXiBcAKHZmgDzIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=selection%20rules%20for%20spontaneous%20emission%20are%20all%20the%20same&f=false)) that the selection rules for spontaneous emission are the same as those for stimulated emission and absorption.

The selection rules for stimulated emission and absorption can be derived by looking at the matrix elements:
$$\langle f|\vec r \cdot \vec p |i \rangle$$
where $\vec p$ is the polarization direction of the stimulating/absorbed light beam. Clearly for spontaneous emission we cannot write such a matrix element (since there is no stimulating/absorbed light beam). And hence we would have to find the selection rules in a different way.

From this I have two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to see why spontaneous emission has the same selection rule? (ignoring the fact that we must have $\Delta n\le 0$ for spontaneous emission).
2. Are there any situations when the selection rules for spontaneous emission are different from those for stimulated emission and absorption?

Answer (score 2):

In the semiclassical theory, the initial and final states are just states of the atom, so the matrix element for spontaneous is exactly the same as that for stimulated emission.  The matrix element makes no mention of the state of the radiation field.

In the quantum theory, the initial and final states are product states of the atom and the field, but it factors into a product of a radiation matrix element and an atomic matrix element.  The atomic matrix element is exactly the same as the semiclassical matrix element.  The radiation matrix element is something like $\left<n|a|n+1\right>$ where $a$ is the lowering ladder operator.  That matrix element is non-zero.

So in both the semiclassical and quantum cases, the selection rules for spontaneous emission and stimulated emission  are determined by the same matrix element, so the selection rules are the same.

As far as I can tell, they are always the same.

Comment: You said 'the matrix element makes no mention of the state of the radiation field', but is the matrix element not that of the radiation field (i.e. $\vec r \cdot \vec p$ comes from the radiation field in stimulated emission and absorption)?

Comment: The matrix element is *derived* from the field-atom interaction Hamiltonian, but those operators $r$ and $p$ operate on states of the atom, not of the field.

Comment: Ok so for stimulated emission and absorption $\vec p$ is the polarization of the actual physical EM field that is causing the emission/absorption. In the case of spontaneous emission where is no such field and therefore no such $\vec p$, so what do we use instead?

Comment: Ah.  Perhaps I skipped a step.  We usually take the dipole approximation, in which the field varies slowly enough over the size of the atom that it can be taken to be constant in space.  Then we can write $\vec{p}\cdot\left<f|\vec{r}|i\right>$.   But I'm beginning to wonder if I'm interpreting your question correctly.  I'll take another look at your question.

Comment: I think you have interpreted my question correctly. Am I correct in saying that $\vec p \cdot \vec r$ in the case of a spontaneous emission is that of an 'unobservable electric field' i.e. one with no photons in, such that the probability that the spontaneous emission photon goes into such a field is proportional to $\vec{p}\cdot\left<f|\vec{r}|i\right>$ but much smaller then that if $\vec p\cdot \vec r$ was that of a real electric field. And for which a full explanation of can't be achieved within the semi-classical theory?

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying.   In the semiclassical case the E field is classical:  there is no concept of "observability", and there are no photons.  Furthermore there is no spontaneous emission in the semiclassical approximation.  I've been unclear from the start whether you are concerned with the semiclassical case or the quantum mechanical case.  Perhaps you should tell us which (or is it both?) and be careful to use the corresponding correct language.